# How can I set a local project setting to every sbt project in a multi-project build?

Tags: sbt, scalatest

To make scalatest generate junit XML files we have the following setting:

```
object MyBuild extends Build {
  ...
  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ (testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u", "target/test-report"))
}
```

The problem with this is that it defines the output folder for the JUnix XMLs in a root folder, rather than for each sub-project.

How can I add a general setting that will cause the location of the output to be relative to each sub-project?

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution is to define own method to create project (in this method you can create default settings):

```sbt
    def DefaultProject(name: String, path: String) = Project(name, file(path)).
settings(testOptions in Test += 
Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u",path+"/target/test-report")
    )
```

Then you can define projects like:

```scala
    lazy val genscalaxb = DefaultProject("genscalaxb", "genscalaxb").
settings(scalaxbSettings: _*)


    lazy val converter = DefaultProject("converter", "converter").
settings(instrumentSettings: _*).dependsOn(`genscalaxb`)
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I was hoping to add a fragment that would apply to all projects. More foolproof, in case a project is forgotten.

Comment: This is why I've switched to using .sbt files as much as I can - I'd rather not have to ensure that when somebody comes back in 8 months and adds a new sub-project that they'll have to read through and reverse engineer everything about the build to get it right. As of 0.13.x, there's actually very little that you *can't* do in an .sbt file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .sbt files and not a full Scala build configuration, you can use something like

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.2"
```

in your root .sbt file. This adds a scope modifier to the setting definition that adds it to all projects in the current build.

Comment: I don't have any .sbt files (apart from plugins.sbt).